# Spring Boot RestTemplate post without response type

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, resttemplate

I need to call another api and I am trying to use postForEntity as below:

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(postUrl, request, responseType)
```

Now, the api that I am calling is returning an object of a particular type, let's say CustomerDto. But I am not interested in this object. I just want to post and I don't want anything in return so I don't want to create this CustomerDto class in my application. So, for this scenario, in the above statement, what should i replace for responseType. In case, I had wanted the returned object, I would have given CustomerDto.class in case of responseType, but I dont want anything in return, so what do I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `postForLocation` instead of `postForEntity`.

```
restTemplate.postForLocation(postUrl, request)
```

Comment: Thanks much for the solution. :)

Comment: I would still appreciate if Spring would add a simple `restTemplate.post(url)` method. There are use cases where the response can simply be ignored. `postForLocation` works fine, but the method name looks awkward, if the return is simply ignored.

Answer (score 13):

Another way is to use `Void.class` as response-type